# Replace values in a pandas dataframe crashes the kernel

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe with 10 columns with integers:

```
site1 site2 site3 ... site10
55    56    198 ...   340
10    101   200 ...   900
...
1     1090  500 ...   300
```

I have a dictionary to replace some of these values:

```
dict = { "55" : "198" .... }
```

when I do:

df.replace(dict)

my kaggle kernel crashes. the df has 350k rows. the dict has 15k

I'm guessing it's too much for the kernel to process. How to do this without crashing the kernel?

Thanks!

Comment: Your `dict` doesn't look right - it should be `{"55": "198", ...}

Answer (score 0):

I ran replace on every series with a loop. no more crashing